# Vscode Docker Compose not making it past setup on remote machine

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am remoting in to a raspberry pi to do all my programming.
The machine is running OpenMediaVault with Docker and Portainer Installed.
If anyone needs to know exactly what I do and install, I have it all documented.

I've been doing this for a while and it works great, I want to start using docker containers on this machine for developing as to avoid complications with the machine itself.

I tried running the `Try A Dev Container Sample` on vscode and selected Python,
The problem im having is it gets stuck immediately on setup.

```
[152129 ms] Dev Containers 0.255.4 in VS Code 1.72.2 (d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075).
[152129 ms] Start: Run: ssh raspberrypi /bin/sh
[152140 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
```

Nothing more happens after these 3 lines,
I've tried leaving this for a while but it does not progress past this stage and I cannot find anybody who has had this problem.

Comment: Does it require any keyboard input before connecting (for example, a password)? `ssh raspberrypi`

Comment: When I launch the ssh session I put my password in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Dev Containers 0.262.1-pre-release.

Updating should solve the problem